# Removing lag from Camera video stream using Opencv/Gstreamer

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, camera, gstreamer

I have a camera application that will display the cameras live stream:

```
void MainWindow::on_start()
{

    if(video.isOpened())
    {

        video.release();
        return;
    }

    if(!isCameraFound || !video.open(pipeline.trimmed().toStdString(), cv::CAP_GSTREAMER))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,
                                "Video Error",
                                "Must be the correct USB Camera connected!");
        return;
    }


    Mat frame;
    while(video.isOpened())
    {
        video >> frame;
        


        if(!frame.empty())
        {
            QImage qimg(frame.data,
                        frame.cols,
                        frame.rows,
                        frame.step,
                        QImage::Format_RGB888);
            pixmap.setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(qimg.rgbSwapped()) );
            ui->graphicsView->fitInView(&pixmap, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        }
...
```

And I have a function that does processing and has a loop to inspect the first 250 frames because the camera gives off a specific frame when something is found. But when doing this loop the videostream lags so much it basically freezes until the loop is done. How would I be able to go about removing the lag caused by the frame grabbing loop to be able to go through the loop and have the videostream not lag?

```
void MainWindow::on_push()
{
Mat test;

    for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++){

        video >> test; 
...
```

Comment: because you are reading and processing the video in the same thread

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan Which method of multithreading would be best do you think?

Comment: If you clarify more, what do you want to do I can help. What will you do with first 250 frames? Is video processed periodically or only are you interested in first frames? What will you do with result of processing 250 frames?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan I am simply analyzing the pixel values of the frames, because when a certain object is found by the camera, it will displayt a specific frame that is 700x700 with pixels, and the rest are 0. If the camera does not find it, It sends two completely black frames. It is usually found/not found in the first 250 so thats why I picked that number.

Comment: If the object is not found though, I want the processing to start over, and do another 250 frames until finally it displays the 700x700 frame.

Comment: For sure, processing of 250 frames will be slower. Even if you process it in another thread, it will take huge time. While processing is done you would buffer new frames coming from video, in this case at some point buffer overflow will happen.  You should do processing in CUDA if possible so that you can get something closer to real time. It is not possible to CPU to process 250 frames under 33ms (1 cycle of camera frames). You should omit %90 of frames, if object was not super fast. so you do not need to process similar frames.Again 25 frames per second is difficult to achieve.